# abort or make_response or jsonify

Tags: python, flask, response

I'm writing Flask web-application and want to know about best practice for returning unsuccessful response. 
Code example:

```
@app.route("/api/model", methods=["DELETE"])
def delete_models():
    """
    Deleting all models.
    """
    try:
        model_service.delete_all_models()
        response = make_response(jsonify(success=True))
    except Exception as ex:
        response = make_response(jsonify(str(ex)), 500)
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
    return response
```

I found theree different approaches.

1. `return jsonify(success=False)`
2. `abort(404, description="There is no model with this index!")`
3. ````
   response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
   return response```
   ````

Which one is the best way? What advantages and disadvantages in each of them?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the error handler decorator of flask, as it explained in the [doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/apierrors/).

For example:

```
@app.errorhandler(InvalidUsage)
def handle_invalid_usage(error):
    response = jsonify(error.to_dict())
    response.status_code = error.status_code
    # Log here the error
    return response

# In your exception or error control use:
raise InvalidUsage('This view is gone', status_code=410)
```